# Incomplete \iffalse in specific lstlisting regardless of contents

Tags: bibliographies, compiling, lstlisting

I have a LaTeX code which gives me these errors at a specific line :

- `Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 140.`
- `Forbidden control sequence found while scanning text of \write.` at line 140

and then in at the end of the document:

- `Argument of \@gobble has an extra }. \end{document}`
- `Missing } inserted. \end{document}`
- etc.

The following code threw the error (line 140 being `y[ row[i] ] += ...` in `\section{COO Kernel}`):

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,czech,american]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=4cm,bmargin=3cm,lmargin=3cm,rmargin=2cm,headheight=0.8cm,headsep=1cm,footskip=0.5cm}
\pagestyle{headings}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter

\newenvironment{lyxlist}[1]
{\begin{list}{}
{\settowidth{\labelwidth}{#1}
 \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}
 \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}
 \renewcommand{\makelabel}[1]{##1\hfil}}}
{\end{list}}
\usepackage[varg]{txfonts}
\usepackage{indentfirst}

\clubpenalty=9500

\widowpenalty=9500

\hyphenation{CDFA HARDI HiPPIES IKEM InterTrack MEGIDDO MIMD MPFA DICOM ASCLEPIOS MedInria}

\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.95}
\newcommand{\code}[1]{\colorbox{light-gray}{\texttt{#1}}}

\definecolor{listinggray}{gray}{0.9}
\definecolor{lbcolor}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}
\definecolor{Darkgreen}{rgb}{0.0, 0.2, 0.13}
\lstset{
    backgroundcolor=\color{lbcolor},
    tabsize=4,    
    language=[GNU]C++,
    basicstyle=\scriptsize,
    upquote=true,
    aboveskip={0.001\baselineskip},
    columns=fixed,
    showstringspaces=false,
    extendedchars=false,
    breaklines=true,
    prebreak = \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\hookleftarrow}},
    frame=single,
    numbers=left,
    showtabs=false,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    identifierstyle=\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\color[rgb]{0,0,1},
    commentstyle=\color[rgb]{0.026,0.112,0.095},
    stringstyle=\color[rgb]{0.627,0.126,0.941},
    numberstyle=\color[rgb]{0.205, 0.142, 0.73},
}
\lstset{
    backgroundcolor=\color{lbcolor},
    tabsize=4,
    language=C++,
    captionpos=b,
    tabsize=3,
    frame=lines,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny,
    numbersep=5pt,
    breaklines=true,
    showstringspaces=false,
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,
    keywordstyle=\color[rgb]{0,0,1},
    commentstyle=\color{Darkgreen},
    stringstyle=\color{red},
}
\lstset{
    morekeywords={__global__},
    alsoletter={.},
    morekeywords={blockDim.x},
    morekeywords={blockIdx.x},
    morekeywords={threadIdx.x}
}

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents{}

\chapter*{Implementation/Kernels of formats}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Implementation/Kernels of formats}

\setcounter{chapter}{3}
\setcounter{section}{0}

\section{DIAG Kernel}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption= SpMV pseudocode using DIAG format for storing a matrix from \textit{Efficient sparse matrix-vector multiplication on CUDA} \cite{Bell-Garland}.]
__global__ void
spmv_dia_kernel ( const int num_rows,
                        const int num_cols,
                        const int num_diags,
                        const int   * offsets,
                        const float * data,
                        const float * x,
                                float * y )
{
    int row = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    if ( row < num_rows ){
          float dot = 0;

          for ( int n = 0; n < num_diags; n++ ){
                  int col = row + offsets[ n ];
                  float val = data[ num_rows * n + row ];

                  if ( col >= 0 && col < num_cols )
                        dot += val * x[ col ];
          }

          y[ row ] += dot;
    }
}
\end{lstlisting}
\label{Code:Diagonal-matrix-example}

\section{COO Kernel}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption= SpMV pseudocode using COO format for storing a matrix \cite{Parallel-Uppsala}.]
__global__ void
spmv_coo_kernel ( const int num_non_zero_elements,
                       const float * data,
                       const int   * row,
                       const int   * col,
                       const float * x,
                               float * y )
{
    int i = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    if ( row < num_non_zero_elements )
          y[ row[i] ] += data[i] * x[ col[i] ];
}
\end{lstlisting}

\section{ELL Oriented Kernels}

\subsection{ELL Kernel}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption = SpMV pseudocode using ELL format for storing a matrix from \textit{Efficient sparse matrix-vector multiplication on CUDA} \cite{Bell-Garland}.]
__global__ void
spmv_ell_kernel ( const int num_rows,
                       const int num_cols,
                       const int num_cols_per_row,
                       const int   * indices,
                       const float * data,
                       const float * x,
                            float * y )
{
    int row = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;

    if( row < num_rows ){
         float dot = 0;

         for ( int n = 0; n < num_cols_per_row; n++ ){
                int col = indices[ num_rows * n + row ];
                float val = data[ num_rows * n + row ];

                 if ( val != 0 )
                       dot += val * x[ col ];
         }

         y[ row ] += dot;
    }
}
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem{Bell-Garland}N Bell, M. Garland: \emph{Efficient sparse matrix-vector multiplication on CUDA}. NVIDIA Technical Report NVR-2008-004, NVIDIA Corporation, 1-32, 2008.

\bibitem{Parallel-Uppsala}D. Lukarski: \emph{Sparse Matrix-Vector Multiplication and Matrix Formats}. Parallel Algorithms for Scientific Computing, Uppsala University, 2013. \url{https://www.it.uu.se/education/phd_studies/phd_courses/pasc/lecture-1}
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

For some reason, citations to `bibitem`s are undefined, even though there don't seem to be any spelling error.

To even compile the document correctly if I roll back the changes that led to the error, I have to delete the `.aux` and `.toc` files.

I'm pretty much dumb founded.

PS: The preamble was created by a professor as a template for all students to use, I was told not to meddle with it.

[EDIT]: Created minimal same-error outputting example as suggested.

[EDIT]: Added log file.

[EDIT]: Removed GitHub link, full project link and log file link, since they aren't necessary for the answer. I'll put them in a [separate folder](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1CQCkQZi-aGuyat0ZXMIylcWE_rS4J66G) and won't remove it, if anyone wants to look at them. If for any reason the links will be broken, please let me know, and I'll renew them somehow, since I'll be keeping a backup of said files aswell.

Comment: Don't link to external files like that. Try to make a complete minimal example that you can copy here.

Comment: But try if it works if you remove the \cite command.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The problem with this error, is that it seems to all be connected, not specific `lstlisting` based, so I have no idea which parts are actually causing it. That's why I included the example where it happens and then the entire code for context.

I tried removing all cite commands and each of them separately, still exactly the same output.

Comment: Well I won't go to some external site, download a complete project  and debug your code. Copy your code to some test folder and then start to remove stuff until you get something small enough that you can post it here.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I've edited my question, tried to minimize the entire document to the relevant code. It's still 184 lines, but if I delete some more, it loses the error producing structure.

Comment: I get no error with your document. Show your log-file. Then I will compare it with mine.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Added log file as shareable file on Google Drive.

Comment: as previously requested, don't link to external sites, this question and any answers are archived forever and won't make sense if that drive link breaks

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I tried to put it in the body, but it exceeded the character count.

Comment: @Kappasenpai I tried the code in GitHub, but it compiles fine, except for the missing images.

Comment: @egreg That is correct, the code on GitHub shows the last working example. If I try to add anything into the `lstlisting` on line 788, it won't work.

Comment: Update your tex system - most importantly the listings package. With the newest version it works again. (Check for updates in user *and*
admin mode).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That fixed the local issue (code in this question's body), but the whole project code didn't compile, with the same errors. Should I close this question and open another question once I've managed to isolate the problem further?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Apologies for the spam, if you could please post your comment about updating the tex system as an answer, I'll accept it, since it solved this issue. Thank you very much for your help. I'll create a new question for the continuing related issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem was to update my MiKTeX in user and admin mode, just like @UlrikeFischer said:

> Update your tex system - most importantly the listings package. With the newest version it works again. (Check for updates in user and admin mode).

Apologies for stealing the answer, I just want to close this solved question and not spam further, by asking for a comment to be written as an answer.

If you would like for me to accept your answer, please, answer anytime, and I'll accept it back.