# Incomplete \iffalse related listlisting, \textit and \textcolor

Tags: errors, color, compiling, text, lstlisting

I've asked [something similar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/477417/incomplete-iffalse-in-specific-lstlisting-regardless-of-contents) before, but that specific issue has been solved (waiting for comment to be posted as answer as of 2.3.19 18:12 GMT+1).

I have a LaTeX code which gives me these errors at a specific line :

- `Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 157.`
- `Forbidden control sequence found while scanning text of \write.` at line 157

The following code threw the error (line 157 being `y[ row[i] ] += ...` in `\section{COO Kernel}`):

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,czech,american]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=4cm,bmargin=3cm,lmargin=3cm,rmargin=2cm,headheight=0.8cm,headsep=1cm,footskip=0.5cm}
\pagestyle{headings}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter

\newenvironment{lyxlist}[1]
{\begin{list}{}
{\settowidth{\labelwidth}{#1}
 \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}
 \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}
 \renewcommand{\makelabel}[1]{##1\hfil}}}
{\end{list}}

\usepackage[varg]{txfonts}
\usepackage{indentfirst}

\clubpenalty=9500
\widowpenalty=9500

\hyphenation{CDFA HARDI HiPPIES IKEM InterTrack MEGIDDO MIMD MPFA DICOM ASCLEPIOS MedInria}
\newcommand{\UNASSIGNED}{\textcolor{red}{UNASSIGNED}}
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}

\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.95}
\newcommand{\code}[1]{\colorbox{light-gray}{\texttt{#1}}}

\definecolor{listinggray}{gray}{0.9}
\definecolor{lbcolor}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}
\definecolor{Darkgreen}{rgb}{0.0, 0.2, 0.13}
\lstset{
    backgroundcolor=\color{lbcolor},
    tabsize=4,    
    language=[GNU]C++,
    basicstyle=\scriptsize,
    upquote=true,
    aboveskip={0.001\baselineskip},
    columns=fixed,
    showstringspaces=false,
    extendedchars=false,
    breaklines=true,
    prebreak = \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\hookleftarrow}},
    frame=single,
    numbers=left,
    showtabs=false,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    identifierstyle=\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\color[rgb]{0,0,1},
    commentstyle=\color[rgb]{0.026,0.112,0.095},
    stringstyle=\color[rgb]{0.627,0.126,0.941},
    numberstyle=\color[rgb]{0.205, 0.142, 0.73},
}
\lstset{
    backgroundcolor=\color{lbcolor},
    tabsize=4,
    language=C++,
    captionpos=b,
    tabsize=3,
    frame=lines,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny,
    numbersep=5pt,
    breaklines=true,
    showstringspaces=false,
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,
    keywordstyle=\color[rgb]{0,0,1},
    commentstyle=\color{Darkgreen},
    stringstyle=\color{red},
}
\lstset{
    morekeywords={__global__},
    alsoletter={.},
    morekeywords={blockDim.x},
    morekeywords={blockIdx.x},
    morekeywords={threadIdx.x}
}

\raggedbottom
\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents{}

\chapter*{Implementation/Kernels of formats}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Implementation/Kernels of formats}

\setcounter{chapter}{3}
\setcounter{section}{0}

\section{DIAG Kernel}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption= SpMV pseudocode using DIAG format for storing a matrix from \textit{Efficient sparse matrix-vector multiplication on CUDA} \cite{Bell-Garland}.]
__global__ void
spmv_dia_kernel ( const int num_rows,
                        const int num_cols,
                        const int num_diags,
                        const int   * offsets,
                        const float * data,
                        const float * x,
                                float * y )
{
    int row = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    if ( row < num_rows ){
          float dot = 0;

          for ( int n = 0; n < num_diags; n++ ){
                  int col = row + offsets[ n ];
                  float val = data[ num_rows * n + row ];

                  if ( col >= 0 && col < num_cols )
                        dot += val * x[ col ];
          }

          y[ row ] += dot;
    }
}
\end{lstlisting}

\textcolor{red}{DO I DESCRIBE THE CODE?} according to my notes in
\textit{Efficient sparse matrix-vector multiplication on CUDA} 
%\cite{Bell-Garland}.

\section{COO Kernel}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption= SpMV pseudocode using COO format for storing a matrix \cite{Parallel-Uppsala}.]
__global__ void
spmv_coo_kernel ( const int num_non_zero_elements,
                       const float * data,
                       const int   * row,
                       const int   * col,
                       const float * x,
                               float * y )
{
    int i = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    if ( row < num_non_zero_elements )
          y[ row[i] ] += data[i] * x[ col[i] ];
}
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem{Bell-Garland}N Bell, M. Garland: \emph{Efficient sparse matrix-vector multiplication on CUDA}. NVIDIA Technical Report NVR-2008-004, NVIDIA Corporation, 1-32, 2008.

\bibitem{Parallel-Uppsala}D. Lukarski: \emph{Sparse Matrix-Vector Multiplication and Matrix Formats}. Parallel Algorithms for Scientific Computing, Uppsala University, 2013. \url{https://www.it.uu.se/education/phd_studies/phd_courses/pasc/lecture-1}
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

The culprit in this case are the `\textcolor` and `\textit` lines, that are located right after the first block of C++ code wrapped in `lstlisting` and right before `\section{COO Kernel}`.

If both of these lines are not commented simultaneously, then the compiler will spew aforementioned errors, however, any other combination (in those 3 lines) that doesn't include these two simultaneously will compile fine.

Anybody know what the cause could be?

PS: The preamble was created by a professor as a template for all students to use, I was told not to meddle with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the czech option. This language makes the hyphen active. 
In your example there is a page break in the middle of listing. That means that the caption with the `Parallel-Uppsala` is written while the listings settings are active and then the hyphen breaks.

You could disable the active hyphen with `\shorthandoff{-}` or use `\string-` in the cite command:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,czech,american]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=4cm,bmargin=3cm,lmargin=3cm,rmargin=2cm,headheight=0.8cm,headsep=1cm,footskip=0.5cm}
%\pagestyle{headings}
%\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\usepackage{listings}


\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}

blb
\vspace{0.8\textheight}

%\shorthandoff{-} %<--

\begin{lstlisting}[caption= SpMV pseudocode using COO format for storing a matrix \cite{Parallel\string-Uppsala}. %<-- or \string
]
__global__ void
spmv_coo_kernel ( const int num_non_zero_elements,
                       const float * data,
                       const int   * row,
                       const int   * col,
                       const float * x,
                               float * y )
{
    int i = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    if ( row < num_non_zero_elements )
          y[ row[i] ] += data[i] * x[ col[i] ];
}
\end{lstlisting}


\end{document}
```