# Problem with `listings`, `babel`, and `zref`:

Tags: listings, babel, zref

[listings 1.8d]
[zref 2.32]
[babel 3.54]

I spent an evening to reduce my real-world example to the following code.

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{zref}


\begin{document}

\makeatletter

\zref@newlist{foo}
\zref@newprop{text}{??}
\zref@addprop{foo}{text}

\zref@setcurrent{text}{">}
\zref@labelbylist{1}{foo}

\vspace*{20cm}

\begin{lstlisting}
  foo
  \l
  \r
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

It fails with

```
[1
! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 23.
<inserted text> 
                \fi 
l.23   \l
```

The problem is most certainly a variant of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/477449/incomplete-iffalse-related-listlisting-textit-and-textcolor): If I replace `">` with `»` the example works fine.

Hopefully, this report helps other people find a solution – I don't really expect an answer to this question except 'fixed in version x.y.z' :-)

Answer (score 1):

It is the same problem as in the other question: listings redefines `"` and when this redefinition is active at shipout it affects the writing of your text (you can get something similar with normal \label too, it is not specific to zref). You could e.g. protect it:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{zref}


\begin{document}

\makeatletter

\zref@newlist{foo}
\zref@newprop{text}{??}
\zref@addprop{foo}{text}

\zref@setcurrent{text}{\protect">}
\zref@labelbylist{1}{foo}

\vspace*{20cm}

\begin{lstlisting}
  foo
  \l
  \r
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I wonder whether the opposite is possible, namely to make `listings` not redefine `"`...

Comment: no, not really listings has to process every char/token one by one, you wouldn't want `"a` in a listing to give ä, wouldn't you?

Comment: Well, I wouldn't use `"` at all in a `listings` environment...

Comment: " can be quite often in listings, e.g. for a hexidezimal number, or a string in lua.

Comment: I don't doubt that.  However, for my use-case I wouldn't need it.

BTW, would there be a theoretical possibility that the problem gets fixed?  I mean, could the shipout stuff be completely isolated from interferences with packages like `listings` (on whatever side the necessary changes are done)?

Comment: well you can't isolate the shipout from the surrounding, e.g. in the \write you want the current meaning of \thepage. You could detect in the shipout if listings is active and add some guards, but imho it would be quite some work for a rather rare case. listings could also preprocess the whole listing in memory in one go and then output it at the end, then it wouldn't be active at the shipout.

Comment: The last solution seems the way to go IMHO, given that memory constraints are not as tight today.  Thanks for the explanation!